# How to index an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have a working code, but I was wondering if there's a better way to do de same. I tried some php array functions but without success maybe I'm using them in a wrong way.

```
$object1 = new stdClass;
$object1->name  = 'John Doe';
$object1->token = 123;

$object2 = new stdClass;
$object2->name  = 'Mary Doe';
$object2->token = 123;

$data = array(
    $object1,
    $object2
);

foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    $new_array[$value->token][] = $value;
}

var_dump($new_array);die;
```

This code gives me exactly what I want,a new array indexed by token property, but for some reason this code doesn't seems write. What should I do better?

**Edit**
I would like to get the same output without the foreach, maybe using some array function form php.

Comment: Initialise `$new_array` before the loop.

Comment: What exactly is your criteria for "better".  If it does exactly what you want, why do you think it is not right?

Comment: *"But for some reason this code doesn't seems write"* ... This code is supposed to do exactly what you want. Can you please provide us with the unexpected result that makes you think the code is not correct ? may be it is because something else other than this code

Comment: I would like to get the same result without the foreach statement

Comment: If you know what you want upfront, why not initialize it immediately? `$new_array = [$object1->token => [$object1], $object2->token => [$object2]];`

Comment: The data was just an example, the real data comes from the DB

Comment: @ArturComunello Perhaps your should provide some real data then.  Will the objects really have the same token, as shown above?  Also, how are you _actually_ creating the `$data` array?  If you have many objects (filled with db data) I highly doubt that you have hardcoded `$object1`, `$object2`, etc.

Comment: The data array will be dynamic, lets say with thousands objects, but some of the tokens are not unique. Idk if I was clear enough

Comment: I'm trying to use less the foreach statement and more native functions.

Comment: Ultimately, I feel like this should be done when you create `$data`, or even _instead of_ it.  Without seeing how you're doing that, any answer is really missing any point of optimization that you have.

Comment: Our grandfathers had to use foreach. use array_map and array_* to impress your colleagues whenever you can.

Comment: I would relieve of their duties any developer who wrote code simply to look impressive.

Comment: @PaulCrovella ah! I forgot the winking smiley face - after all this SO and means serious business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fancyArray = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $value) {
    $carry[$value->token][] = $value;
    return $carry;
});

var_dump($fancyArray);
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: That's exactly was I was looking for! Thanks @madflow

Comment: Avoid "thank you" comments; there's systems in place to thank posters for their time. So, if this answer provides the solution you were looking for, consider upvoting/accepting the answer.

Comment: I can't upvote @TimLewis, I'm still learning, thanks haha

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think there were any restrictions on your own question. Could be wrong. You should be able to accept the answer (checkmark beside this answer) regardless. And no worries; I know you're a new contributor; just something to be aware of.